# Implicit conversion: uint32 to int

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm working on getting an app compatible with iPhone 6, and mostly have just run into type casting issues that need to be resolved.  But no matter how I cast this one, I can't get the build to complete successfully.

```
inline void MTRand::seed( uint32 *const bigSeed, const uint32 seedLength ){
    // N is set to 628 up above
    register uint32 j = 0;
    register int k = (N > seedLength ? N : seedLength);  // build fail on this line
    // do more stuff
```

I thought changing it to

```
register int k = (N > seedLength ? (int)N : (int)seedLength);
```

would work, but I still get the ***'Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'const uint32' (aka 'const unsigned long') to 'int'*** error.  I'm pretty new to iOS development, so this could be something simple that I'm missing.  Any tips?

Comment: What is the datatype of `N`? Why not change `k` to be `uint32` instead of `int`?

Comment: N is just int type (public: enum{N = 624}).  I've tried casting k as uint32 and it still complains about the implicit conversion.

Comment: Just a guess, but do you need to cast the comparison as well as the two possible values: `register int k = ((int)N > (int)seedLength ? (int)N : (int)seedLength);`

Comment: I ended up getting it to work with the line that I thought would work, but the error message wasn't getting updated on build for some reason.  As soon as I closed/reopened XCode, it built fine.

Comment: `register int k = static_cast<int>(N > seedLength ? N : seedLength);`

Answer (score 0):

Cast all of the values to (int), not just the comparison.

```
register int k = ( (int)N > (int)seedLength ? (int)N : (int)seedLength);
```